# Big calender in react.js , how to setup localization?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to run the big calender app in my fresh install of `create-react-app` , the code in my App.js looks like so::-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar'
import events from './events'

let allViews = Object.keys(BigCalendar.Views).map(k => BigCalendar.Views[k])

let App = () => (
  <BigCalendar
    events={events}
    views={allViews}
    step={60}
    showMultiDayTimes
    defaultDate={new Date(2015, 3, 1)}
  />
)

export default App;
```

But i get the following error:

[image: bigcalender]

I have basically copied the code from the basic big calender example([HERE](http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html)) but i still get this error , why am i getting this error ? how do setup localization for using big calender ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I've done it:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar'
import moment from 'moment'; // new
import 'moment/locale/nb';   // new
import events from './events'

const messages = { // new
  allDay: 'hele dagen',
  previous: 'forrige',
  next: 'neste',
  today: 'i dag',
  month: 'måned',
  week: 'uke',
  day: 'dag',
  agenda: 'agenda',
  date: 'dato',
  time: 'tid',
  event: 'hendelse',
};

let allViews = Object.keys(BigCalendar.Views).map(k => BigCalendar.Views[k])

let App = () => (
  <BigCalendar
    events={events}
    views={allViews}
    messages={messages} // new
    step={60}
    showMultiDayTimes
    defaultDate={new Date(2015, 3, 1)}
  />
)

export default App;
```

Install moment and import it, as well as the locale that you want to use. In my case, it's *nb*. This will switch the date/time format to my country's standard, but if you also want to have the labels in your language you have to change the messages too. Create a `messages` object, translate the strings like I've done and use it as a parameter to the calendar component.

This works for v0.17.0. I haven't tried v0.18.0.

Comment: how did u install moment ? `npm install react-moment` ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik I'm thinking of the normal moment package. `npm install moment`.